# How to calculate inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I do not know how  to calculate the inverse of the matrix. 
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 &\\
  \beta^{2m}_{1} &     \beta^{2m-1}_{1}  &     \beta^{2m-2}_{1}  &   \beta^{m+1}_{1} &1\\ 
   \beta^{2m}_{2} &     \beta^{2m-1}_{2}  &     \beta^{2m-2}_{2}  &   \beta^{m+1}_{2} &1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\
   \beta^{2m}_{m-1} &     \beta^{2m-1}_{m-1}  &     \beta^{2m-2}_{m-1}  &   \beta^{m+1}_{m-1} &1 \\
 \beta^{2m}_{m} &     \beta^{2m-1}_{m}  &     \beta^{2m-2}_{m}  &   \beta^{m+1}_{m} &1
\end{vmatrix}
where $m \geq 2$ and all $\beta_i>1$ are different.

Comment: You have a Vandermonde matrix, google on this (i.e., Vandermonde matrix) and you will find a lot of information.

Comment: actually , it is not a Vandermonde matrix

Comment: Where did you find this matrix? There may not be a useful closed-form solution, in particular because when $m$ is a large number that matrix becomes fairly ill-conditioned to start with. I don't mean to imply that there is no closed form solution, but that formula is likely not going to be numerically stable. It may be better to try to invert that matrix numerically with preconditioned LU decomposition, or some other algorithm which can invert ill-conditioned matrices.

Comment: what is the exponent in each column, is it all integer values $1$ to $2m$? If so, it is a Vandermonde matrix. If not, can you specify the exponents? I am confused as you have the $\ldots$ (dots) in the first row but no other row...

Comment: m is an integer , I come across this matrix in dynamical system and fractal and if I calculate the inverse, then I will find a surprising result.....

Comment: in the first row there are all 1.

Comment: we should note that there is no $\beta^{m}\,,\beta^{m-1}\dots \beta$, so it is not a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: I want to calculate the determinant firstly: \begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 &\\
     \beta^{2m-1}_{1}  &     \beta^{2m-2}_{1}  &   \beta^{m+1}_{1} &1\\ 
    \beta^{2m-1}_{2}  &     \beta^{2m-2}_{2}  &   \beta^{m+1}_{2} &1 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\
    \beta^{2m-1}_{m-1}  &     \beta^{2m-2}_{m-1}  &   \beta^{m+1}_{m-1} &1 \\
\beta^{2m-1}_{m}  &     \beta^{2m-2}_{m}  &   \beta^{m+1}_{m} &1
\end{vmatrix}

Comment: For determinant, this might help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial

Comment: So if I understand, it is basically a sub-matrix of the Vandermonde? (also use the @ symbol followed by my username if you are responding to my question)

Answer (score 1):

(This is not quite a solution, but it's getting close.)

We can write your matrix $A$ in partitioned form 
$$
  A = \begin{pmatrix} a^T&1\\ B&a\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a$ is the vector with all entries equal to 1. There is a permutation matrix
$P$ such that
$$
  AP = \begin{pmatrix} 1&a^T\\ a&B\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Assume $B$ is invertible.
$$
  AP = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&B\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ B^{-1}a&I\end{pmatrix}
          \begin{pmatrix} 1&a^T\\ 0&I-B^{-1}aa^T\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now $\det(I-MN)=\det(I-NM)$ for any matrices $M$ and $N$ and so if $M=B^{-1}a$ and $N=a^T$,
then
$$
  \det(I-B^{-1}aa^T) = \det(1-a^TB^{-1}a) = 1 - a^TB^{-1}a.
$$
Therefore $\det(AP) =\det(B) (1-a^TB^{-1}a)$. (Here I am effectively working
out the Schur complement of $B$ in $AP$ explicitly.)

I think that in the question the matrix $B$ is a diagonal matrix times a
Vandermonde matrix, and so we can write down its inverse using Lagrnage interpolating polynomials. I do not see any
easy way to evaluate $a^TB^{-1}a$ though.

Note that we can compute
the inverse of $AP$ using the factorization, provided we can invert $I-B^{-1}J$,
where $J=aa^T$.
For if $\beta:=a^TB^{-1}a$ and $\beta\ne1$, then it is easy to verify that
$$
  (I-B^{-1}J)(I+ \frac1{1-\beta} B^{-1}J) = I.
$$